# Uniform Convergence of Composite Functions using Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose that $ f_n $ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, and that
>   $|f_n(x)|\leq M, |f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b] $. Let $g$ be a
>   function continuous on [-M,M]. Show that $g \circ fn$ converges to $g
>  \circ f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. Hint: Use uniform continuity.

I know that since $g$ is continuous on [-M,M], it is uniformly continuous on [-M,M]. However, I'm not sure how to use this in this case (even though it's in the hint...). Would I say something like:

Since $g$ is uniformly continuous on [-M,M] and  $ f_n $ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ and is bounded by M we can say that $g \circ fn$ converges to $g \circ f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you said, $g$ is uniformly continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $y,z\in [-M,M]$ with $|y-z|<\delta$ then $|g(y)- g(z)|<\epsilon.$

On the other hand, there is $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\delta$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in[a,b].$

By taking $z=f_n(x)\in[-M,M]$ and $y=f(x)\in[-M,M]$, we have shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $|g(f_n(x)) - g(f(x))|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in[a,b].$